# Replacing PubNub with SignalR - Help on design

Tags: signalr

Right now I'm using PubNub to make my web apps communicate. I have two different apps that receive message (so just listen to) via JS and at least three different apps (two web and one worker) that send messages (server to client).

So, with PubNub things are quite simple, from codebehind I make a rest call to their servers and my JS clients receive the messages. I would like to replicate this with SignalR but I'd need a check to the design/architecture I'm going to use.

I was planning to create a .Net web app running SignalR server. Here I create the Hub, configure routes in Global.asax (RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true })). This will be deployed on sr.mydomain.com.

JS clients (deployed as client1.mydomain.com and clientx.mydomain.com) can easily listen to messages sent by sr.mydomain.com setting $.connection.hub.url

So far, everything is fine, coded, tested and is working.

The point is how to send messages to JS clients from webapp.mydomain.com and from MyWorkerRole. I'm thinking about creating a webmethod on sr.mydomain.com that can be consumed from webapp.mydomain.com and from MyWorkerRole. So MyWorkerRole make a call to trhe webmethod on sr.mydomain.com and sr.mydomain.com send the message to client1.mydomain.com. Does it makes sense? There's a better more direct way to do this?

Comment: Just thinking, what are the reasons for moving to SignalR? Is it a scaling issue with PubNub? Do you need some custom functionality that PubNub can't not provide?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will work in single server mode. If you have to scale out sr.mydomain.com to more than one instance, then the obvious issue is that signalr client may not be connected to the node that receives the web service call.

If you need to support scale out, you can use SQL server, Azure service bus or Redis as a backplane. See: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

The 50K ft view is something like this:

1. Create your hub derived from SignalR Hub as usual.
2. On both event producer (web role) and consumer side (your worker role etc), initialize signalr to use a backplane. Of course, in a webapp, you'd stick this in a `Global.asax` along with the `MapHubs` call.

   ```
   GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(redisServer, redisPort, redisPassword, key);
   ```
3. On the producer side (worker role), you can get a `IHubContext` as follows:

   ```
   var hubContext =
           GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
   ```

   now you can send messages with `hubContext.Clients`. Similar to the extension `UseRedis`, there are other extensions like `UseServiceBus`

Comment: Note override available: `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, key))` - useful for Azure